# Copying files using azcopy running in a batch file

Tags: azure, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012-r2, azcopy

I want to execute a batch file (Through Task Scheduler) that runs `azcopy` and copies only the new files to the server. I've succeeded in configuring the task scheduler, but I'm failing to properly execute the batch file.

I've done extensive research through SO and sibling sites and haven't found the solution.

Here's the batch file:

```
azcopy cp "E:\SISTEMA\KORRENET\CSV\*.CSV" "https://x.blob.core.windows.net/data?sp=w&st=2021-07-27T23:15:58Z&se=2022-12-31T07:15:58Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=my-signature-properly-escaped-with-double-ampersands%%3D" --overwrite=false
```

But I'm getting hit with the following problems:

1. Not all of my files in the directory are getting discovered.

[image: Result]

2. When I execute it within the `.bat` file I get "Failed" messages (Final Job Status: Failed). When I copy and paste the command directly into CMD it "Skips" the files (Still doesn't discover the new ones) (Final Job Status: CompleteWithSkipped).
3. I'm also getting 2 files that failed  (There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request).

Here is when I copy and paste the command directly into cmd:

[image: Snip of the CMD output window when running it directly from the CMD]

I want to copy the  non-existent .CSV files inside the directory.

Comment: I guess information about the setup of the Scheduled Task would help to help you…

Comment: Hi @aschipfl, currently it's firing up. My problem right now is manually executing the batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use sync for copying new files only from local to azure and you can add include pattern to filter out the required file types you want to sync .

For batch file not working , it may be because you have “%” in your SAS token ,so you need to add another “%” infront of it for the .bat file to work properly .

Another reason could be, it doesn’t have the proper permissions in the SAS token. I see you have given only **write** permission but for copy job it requires **read and write**.

**Command for Sync Job:**

```
azcopy sync "C:\SO threads" "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/test?sp=racwdl&st=2021-08-14T12:57:47Z&se=2021-08-14T20:57:47Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=ZyL88888888888888ETq8N94I3rn1vM%%3D" --include-pattern "*.docx" --recursive=true
```

So as I have 1 "%" here i.e. %3D , I have added 1 more infront of it to make it work.

**Note:** If there is a mistake in SAS token signature or permission then it will result in failed like below and if you go to the log then you can see why it failed .

[image]

[image]

In my example I am only syncing ”.docx file” in the local folder to the container. You can change it as per your requirement.

**Working Example:**

[image]

**Note :** Please provide all permissions while generating a SAS for sync Job and if you are using copy then please provide read and write permissions.

Then for scheduling you can use the below command from cmd:

```
schtasks /CREATE /SC minute /MO 5 /TN "AzCopy Script" /TR C:\script.bat
```

**Reference:** [Tutorial: Migrate on-premises data to Azure Storage with AzCopy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-migrate-on-premises-data?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=windows)